# Storing another array's values in an array using foreach

Tags: php, arrays

This is my code:

```
$videos_key = array();
foreach($result[$x]["videos_key"] as $videos_key  ) 
    {
        $videos_key[] = $result[$x]["videos_key"];
    }


print $videos_key;
```

Here `$result[$x]["videos_key"]`is an array, which have values. It is inside an forloop, so `[$x]` is an number like: 0,1,2,3...

I want to transfer it's value to  $videos_key

Errors:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

2nd error

> Notice: Array to string conversion

Comment: What is the result of `$result`?

Comment: `$result = $stmt->fetchAll();` It store database values

Comment: Please show us `var_dump($result);`.  We need to see what's being returned from the database.

Comment: string(11) "vZ734NWnAHA" 
string(11) "i-vsILeJ8_8"

Comment: So that is why `foreach` is complaining; you are attempting to pass something that doesn't exist to the `foreach` loop.

Comment: oh...Mybad, this question can be closed

Answer (score 0):

Invalid argument supplied for foreach()?? $result[$x]["videos_key"] is an array???

```
$videos_key = array();
 if (is_array($result[$x]["videos_key"])){
    foreach($result[$x]["videos_key"] as $key => $value  ) 
      {
        array_push($videos_key,$value);
      }
 }else{
       echo "no array";
 }

echo print_r($videos_key, true);
```

Comment: `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() ` 2nd error

`Notice: Array to string conversion`